# DataFlow not able to read API response json file stored in Blob Storage

Tags: dataflow, azure-data-factory

[json structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed85b.png)Data Flow is not able to read the API response json file stored in blob storage, if the file is manually placed in the same location it works fine, but for the json api response dataflow says corrupted file? In dataset I'm able to preview the file but in data flow it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show us your structure of the json file?

Comment: I've created a same test and got no errors, this seems to be a matter of individual differences.

Comment: Hey @JosephXu I've the attached the structure to the post

Comment: You may be hitting this error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-troubleshoot-guide#error-code-df-executor-systeminvalidjson.Try changing the document form in the source options under JSON options.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is JSON parsing error, see: [Error code: DF-Executor-SystemInvalidJson](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-troubleshoot-guide#error-code-df-executor-systeminvalidjson).

> - **Message:** JSON parsing error, unsupported encoding or multiline
> - **Causes:** Possible issues with the JSON file: unsupported encoding, corrupt  bytes, or using JSON source as single document on
>   many nested lines
> - **Recommendation:** Verify the JSON file's encoding is supported. On the  Source transformation that is using a JSON dataset, expand
>   'JSON  Settings' and turn on 'Single Document'.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar sort of issue. The same dataset that saves the file on Blob storage wasn't able to read it back through dataflow. However, preview from dataset works great. So, I checked the saved file encoding and found somehow it is getting saved with UTF-8-BOM encoding even when my dataset is configured to save it as default UTF-8.
Changing the encoding back to UTF-8 in my notepad++ and after replacing old with new in blob worked great using the same dataset. But this was not a permanent solution.

For permanent solution, I created a new dataset with same UTF-8 as default encoding for dataflow. Now I have two separate datasets, one for writing to blob and other for reading from blob. This solution worked as a permanent fix. I don't know what the difference it made by having separate dataset for reading but I am glad that it worked for me.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/632812/malformed-records-are-detected-in-schema-inference-1.html

Good luck!!!